# Need to extract the last node value using xpath3

Tags: dataweave

I have a situation where I have to always select the last line number.

```
<?xml version='1.0'>
<lines>
<line1>line1</line1>
<line2>line2</line2>
<line3>line3</line3>
<line4>line4</line4>
...............
...............
<linen>linen</linen>
</lines>
```

how can I extract last line using xpath3 efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your question `xpath3`, but you have tagged your question with DataWeave (I'm assuming you are using Mule).

Using dataweave, I would use something like

```
field: payload.lines[-1]
```